# Synchronize data in MongoDB in BigQuery with python error json

Tags: python, mongodb, google-bigquery

I am trying to synchronize between 2 databases:
MongoDB and BigQuery

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mongodb1.py", line 53, in <module>
     job = client_bq.load_table_from_json(data, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2366, in load_table_from_json
     data_str = u"\n".join(json.dumps(item) for item in json_rows)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2366, in <genexpr>
     data_str = u"\n".join(json.dumps(item) for item in json_rows)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
     return _iterencode(o, 0)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
     raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 30, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable
```

I made this script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.api_core.retry import Retry
import os
from bson import ObjectId

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'gissoft-378107-19dbaa3080fa.json'

dataset_id = "gissoft-378107.mongodb"
table_id = "sessions"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://codercoder42:xxxxxxxx@cluster0.to2e8pb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    print("Connection Successful")
    db = client['sample_restaurants']
    
    client_bq = bigquery.Client()
    
    
    for collection_name in db.list_collection_names():
    
        
        collection = db[collection_name]
        sample_document = collection.find_one()
        if sample_document is None:
            continue
            
        table_ref = client_bq.dataset('mongodb').table(collection_name)
        schema = []
        for field_name, value in sample_document.items():
            field_type = 'STRING'
            if isinstance(value, int):
                field_type = 'INTEGER'
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                field_type = 'FLOAT'
            elif isinstance(value, bool):
                field_type = 'BOOLEAN'
            schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(field_name, field_type))
    
        table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
        table = client_bq.create_table(table)
    
        
        data = []
        for document in collection.find():
            #print(document)
            data.append(document) 
    
        print(data)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema, write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE")
        job = client_bq.load_table_from_json(data, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
        job.result()
    
    
    client.close()
    client_bq.close()
```

When I send the data to BigQuery, it creates the table with the correct schema, but the data is not entered into the table.

The mongodb table looks like this:

[image]

I think it's a json problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue and load correctly data to `BigQuery`, you have to convert the `datetime` retrieved from `Mongo` to String ISO date, example of [supported date format BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions) : `2008-12-25T05:30:00`

You can apply the conversion with a code that looks like :

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.api_core.retry import Retry
import os
from bson import ObjectId

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'gissoft-378107-19dbaa3080fa.json'

dataset_id = "gissoft-378107.mongodb"
table_id = "sessions"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://codercoder42:xxxxxxxx@cluster0.to2e8pb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    print("Connection Successful")
    db = client['sample_restaurants']
    
    client_bq = bigquery.Client()
    
    
    for collection_name in db.list_collection_names():
    
        
        collection = db[collection_name]
        sample_document = collection.find_one()
        if sample_document is None:
            continue
            
        table_ref = client_bq.dataset('mongodb').table(collection_name)
        schema = []
        for field_name, value in sample_document.items():
            field_type = 'STRING'
            if isinstance(value, int):
                field_type = 'INTEGER'
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                field_type = 'FLOAT'
            elif isinstance(value, bool):
                field_type = 'BOOLEAN'
            schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(field_name, field_type))
    
        table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
        table = client_bq.create_table(table)
    
        
        data = []
        for document in collection.find():
            
            # Date conversion here.
            my_date = document['my_field_date']
            my_date_as_str = current_date.isoformat()
            
            document.update(my_field_date='my_date_as_str')
            
            #print(document)
            data.append(document) 
    
        print(data)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema, write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE")
        job = client_bq.load_table_from_json(data, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
        job.result()
    
    
    client.close()
    client_bq.close()
```

I applied a conversion from datetime to iso string in the `document` object.
So data should be saved correctly to the `BigQuery` table.